# Gibbs Sampler while fixing one parameter

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I came across a problem for Gibbs sampler.

Suppose I want to draw samples from $f(x,y,z)$, Can I use the following scheme to draw samples?

Step 1, draw $f(x^{2t-1},y^t|z^{t-1})$.

Step 2, draw $ f(x^{2t},z^t|y^{t-1})$.

Then, after $T$ steps, we have $2T$ samples for $x$, and $T$ samples for $y$ and $z$.

Is the above procedure appropriate? Could you provide me some references?

Thanks!

Comment: I made a mistake, in step 2, it should be conditional on $y^t$

Comment: The parameter of interest is $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The method is correct by the following reasoning:

Start with $$(x,y,z)\sim f(x,y,z)$$ and apply Step 1.
$$ (x',y') \sim f(x,y|z)$$
then $$(x',y',z)\sim f(x,y,z)$$
Now apply Step 2
$$ (x'',z') \sim f(x,z|y')$$
then $$(x'',y',z')\sim f(x,y,z)$$
This means $f$ is stationary for this two-step Gibbs algorithm.

> **Note:** the title should be corrected as *"fixing one parameter"* is
>   confusing. You could say Gibbs sampling/sampler with two block
>   conditionals.

Comment: @Ryan: can you please change the title?